# How to set focus to Webview control programmatically

Tags: javascript, webview, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 app (runtime) I have a webview control to load html data. I want to move the focus to the webview control and bring up the keyboard on page load. This does not seem to be working:

```
await _webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "focusContent" });
```

What is the correct script to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you know what element id is, you can get focus in it.
You can do it as follow:

```
await _webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.getElementById('txEmail')" });
```

It'll work fine if the control element id is equal to *txEmail*

```
<input type="text" id="txEmail" name="elementToBeFocused" />
```

I hope it Works for you, worked for me ;)